# Transform from ____ to ____ was unavailable for the time requested. Using latest instead

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, robot-localization, joint-state-publisher, robot-state-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run robot_localization in simulation I get the following warning every 2 seconds

```
[ WARN] [1599417511.143838658, 4.002000000]: Transform from puddles/imu_link to puddles/base_link was unavailable for the time requested. Using latest instead.
```

While this warning does not cause any immediate issues, I am concerned it means I have poorly implemented tf or simulated time  somewhere. This occurs in simulation but I have been unable to test it on our actual system. I have use_sim_time set to true, all of my tf publishers are publishing very frequently, and the only way I can get the warning to go away is to set a transform_timeout in robot_localization, which causes failed to update warnings. The systems I have tested this on have been Ubuntu 18.04 ROS Melodic.

This is an underwater application, so I only have 3 sensors, IMU, depth, and DVL. IMU is the only sensor that has ever been referred to in this warning. Here are some more information about my system.

[image: view_frames]

[image: node_graph]

EKF_localization_node params

```
frequency: 30
silent_tf_failure: false
two_d_mode: false
transform_time_offset: 0.0
transform_timeout: 0.0
print_diagnostics: true
debug: false
debug_out_file: /path/to/debug/file.txt
publish_tf: true
publish_acceleration: false

imu0: imu/data
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              false, false, false,
              true,  true,  true,
              true,  true,  true]
imu0_queue_size: 5
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
gravitational_acceleration: 9.81604

twist0: dvl/twist
twist0_config: [false, false, false,
                false, false, false,
                true,  true,  true,
                false, false, false,
                false, false, false]

pose0: depth/pose
pose0_config: [false, false, true,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
```

IMU message published at 100 Hz:

```
header: 
  seq: 1953
  stamp: 
    secs: 19
    nsecs: 716000000
  frame_id: "puddles/imu_link"
orientation: 
  x: 0.0523333914357
  y: -0.35588218556
  z: 0.0330905279149
  w: 0.932477400854
orientation_covariance: [0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0001]
angular_velocity: 
  x: -3.59392461073e-11
  y: 8.47498014701e-12
  z: -2.18380955198e-11
angular_velocity_covariance: [1.1519236000000001e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1519236000000001e-07, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.1519236000000001e-07]
linear_acceleration: 
  x: 6.53786067743
  y: 0.726375271311
  z: 7.26436473382
linear_acceleration_covariance: [1.6e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6e-05, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.6e-05]
```

If you know anything about what this warning is referring to, how to fix it, or how to suppress it, please let me know

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/361046/transform-from-____-to-____-was-unavailable-for-the-time-requested.-using-latest-instead./) by [blaine141](https://answers.ros.org/users/36612/blaine141/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-09-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The reason you see that warning is that you are using a `state_publisher` node that isn't publishing the static transforms on the latched `/tf_static` topic. It's publishing them at a fixed frequency, so once in a while, the state estimation node asks for a transform that hasn't been published yet.

You can safely ignore the warning, since the latest transform that it falls back to is always the same. However, if it bothers you, you can set the `use_tf_static` to *true* on your `state_publisher` node. See this wiki page for details:

http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher

EDIT in response to comments:

Some of your links are using static transforms when you do that (they show up as 10000 Hz), but your IMU link is not (same for a few others). It still shows up as being published at 93 Hz, as do a bunch of your other links. Any chance your URDF doesn't have your `imu_link` as a fixed joint?
[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2020-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [blaine141](https://answers.ros.org/users/36612/blaine141/) on 2020-09-29**:
I have used static before and it didn't work. I tried it again and the warning kept coming every 2 seconds. I should also note no matter the state publisher frequency, the warning comes every 2 seconds

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-09-29**:
Can you show me the transform graph with static enabled?

**Comment by [blaine141](https://answers.ros.org/users/36612/blaine141/) on 2020-09-29**:
https://imgur.com/a/LRyGjDL

**Comment by [blaine141](https://answers.ros.org/users/36612/blaine141/) on 2020-09-29**:
Yes, some of my joints are not fixed and they have to be to simulate in gazebo properly.

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2020-09-29**:
Understood, but that is going to be the the source of that warning. In order for `robot_state_publisher` to publish a joint using `tf2`'s static transform publication, it needs to be a fixed joint. If it's a floating joint, then it will publish non-static messages as some fixed frequency. No matter what the frequency is, if you get an IMU message with a newer timestamp than the latest `imu_link` transform publication, you will get that warning.

**Comment by [blaine141](https://answers.ros.org/users/36612/blaine141/) on 2020-09-29**:
Ok. I will try to make fixed copies of the joints and map the sensor msgs to the static joint.

**Comment by [blaine141](https://answers.ros.org/users/36612/blaine141/) on 2020-09-29**:
It works. I use revolute joints for the sim in gazebo, make a node that remaps it to a fixed joint, then pass that to the EKF. Thank you